# Backbone remove and new view does not reset its attribute array content

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, javascript-objects, backbone-views

I have a view on Backbone with these two attributes:

```
var MyBasketView = Backbone.View.extend({

    _totalCost: 0,
    _devices:  [],
```

and on initialize I go through an array in localStorage with several devices which I push them to the _devices array and sum their total to the _totalCost like this

```
var self = this;
_.each(this._cartItems, function(cartItem) {
    self._totalCost += cartItem.item.cost;
    self._devices.push(cartItem.item);
}
```

In my router I remove this view when I leave this page and I create this view again when I come back. The problem is that when I print the attributes in my initialize function the total cost is at 0 and the devices array still has the devices from before.

Shouldn't it be reset when I remove the view or create it with new MyBasketView()?

I can of course clean it in my initialize, but I would like to understand why this is happening and if it occurs with other Objects as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is the mostly the same as for [`Model.defaults`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults) (the fine prints) :

> Remember that in JavaScript, objects are passed by reference, so if
>   you include an object as a default value, it will be shared among all
>   instances.

When you create new instances of your view, values are copied, including `_devices` that will point to the same array reference :

```
var v1 = new MyBasketView();
var v2 = new MyBasketView();

v1._devices === v2._devices // true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/67pr1gnk/

and the content of that array is kept throughout the life of your `MyBasketView` prototype (even if the instances are destroyed).

The simplest fix is to assign the variable in the `initialize` function:

```
var MyBasketView = Backbone.View.extend({
    _totalCost: 0,
    initialize: function() {
        this._devices = [];
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/67pr1gnk/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Didn't notice that in the model documentation, since I was looking into the views doc. It makes sense but it wasn't what I was expecting when creating a new Object.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be how Backbone works. The object you pass isn't deep-cloned. Setting your non-const variables in `initialize` is probably a better practice.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/jrbxnr0t/